# is there any way to optimize pytorch inference in cpu?

Tags: heroku, pytorch

I am going to serve pytorch model(resnet18) in website.
However, inference in cpu(amd3600) requires 70% of cpu resources.
I don't think the server(heroku) can handle this computation.
Is there any way to optimize inference in cpu?
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, I'm not an expert on Heroku but probably you can use [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html#). OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware but it should work with any CPU. It optimizes the inference performance by e.g. graph pruning or fusing some operations together. [Here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_performance_benchmarks_openvino.html#resnet-18-pytorch-224x224) are the performance benchmarks for Resnet-18 converted from PyTorch.

You can find a full tutorial on how to convert the PyTorch model [here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_performance_benchmarks_openvino.html#resnet-18-pytorch-224x224). Some snippets below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[pytorch,onnx]
```

**Save your model to ONNX**

OpenVINO cannot convert PyTorch model directly for now but it can do it with ONNX model. This sample code assumes the model is for computer vision.

```
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH)
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "model.onnx", opset_version=11)
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert ONNX model**

The Model Optimizer is a command line tool which comes from OpenVINO Development Package so be sure you have installed it. It converts the ONNX model to OV format (aka IR), which is a default format for OpenVINO. It also changes the precision to FP16 (to further increase performance). Run in command line:

```
mo --input_model "model.onnx" --input_shape "[1,3, 224, 224]" --mean_values="[123.675, 116.28 , 103.53]" --scale_values="[58.395, 57.12 , 57.375]" --data_type FP16 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference on the CPU**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device e.g. CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what is the best choice for you, just use AUTO.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="CPU")

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.

Comment: does OpenVINO automatically prunes model without performance issue? that sounds surreal to me. Does it has optimization level hyper parameters? e.g cuda.amp O1/O2

Comment: When I say graph pruning (in this case), I mean these unnecessary nodes that don't change accuracy like identity. No, unfortunately, there are no optimization levels. However, you can reach better performance by converting to FP16 or quantizing (with some accuracy drop)

Comment: If you would like to know more about these optimizations, please visit https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/wiki/Internal-CPU-Plugin-Optimizations

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Intel CPU, please check out Intel Extension for PyTorch. This Intel extension provides quantization features to deliver good accuracy results for large deep learning models.

Check out the article - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/code-sample/accelerate-pytorch-models-using-quantization.html. This article also shows you a code sample on how to accelerate PyTorch-based models by applying Intel Extension for PyTorch quantization.

Additionally, there is a tool called Intel Neural Compressor. It is a model-compression tool that helps to speed up the inference without sacrificing accuracy. Check out this article - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/pytorch-quantization-using-intel-neural-compressor.html to perform INT8 quantization on a PyTorch model and optimize the performance using Intel Neural Compressor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try prune and quantize your model (techniques to compress model size for deployment, allowing inference speed up and energy saving without significant accuracy losses). There are examples in pytorch website with model pruning and quantization, you can check.

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/pruning_tutorial.html
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/dynamic_quantization_tutorial.html

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. But, I am not sure that resnet18 can handle more pruning and quantizing. As far as I know, it is very small model compared to others.